# How to map dictionary to replace a different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

How do I use a dictinoary to replace a different column? (Note "windows" has a leading space)

```
df  col_1             col_2         col_3     col_4
     apple             fruit        test       ama
      windows          house        test2      ama
...
```

```
replace_dict = {'apple': 'Technology company', ' windows' : 'Technology company2'}
df[['col1', 'col2']].replace (replace_dict)
```

Expected Output

```
df  col_1             col_2                     col_3     col_4
     apple             Technology company         test       ama
      windows          Technology company2        test2      ama
...
```

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign replaced value of `col1` to `col2` - if no match get values from `col1` to `col2`:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].replace(replace_dict)
```

If need `col2` if no match use `map` - it return `NaN` if no match, so possible replace `NaN` by original column `col2`:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(replace_dict).fillna(df['col2'])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I actually tried inplace=True. Why didn't that work?

Comment: @asd - When you select the columns for replacement with df[['col1', 'col2']], a slice (a copy) of your dataframe is created. The copy is updated, but never written back into the original dataframe. So original data are not changed.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work since it replaces ```col_1``` with the dictionary value. I was hoping for only ```col_2``` to be replaced by the values i.e. ```col_2``` should be replaced to "Technology company" etc

Comment: @asd - If use `df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].replace (replace_dict, regex=True)` it working? `regex=True` is for substring replacement

Comment: Still replaces ```col_1``` unfortunately

Comment: @asd - Can you check `df['col2'] = df['col1'].replace (replace_dict)` ?

Comment: Perfect, that works. Many thanks @jezrael

Comment: Sorry, do you know why for rows where there is no replacement to be made, it replaces ```col_2``` with ```col_1```? I only need to replace ```col_2``` for the ones mentioned in the dictionary

Comment: @asd - because it assign `col1`. Give me a sec for solution

Comment: Makes sense, confirmed it's all working now. Sorry for all the trouble!

Comment: @asd - No problem, happy coding and nice weekend!

Comment: You too @jezrael!